# What are these "THREE OPTION" phrases specifically called

Tags: etymology, phrases, expressions, expression-choice, popular-refrains

Even though I came up with some pretty good categorizations, I'd still like to get the proper terminology!

What I came up with:
a) Conceptual Beliefs / Actions
b) Philosophical Choices / Options

What are these called?

1) Yes, No or Maybe
2) For, Against or Undecided
3) Guilty, Not Guilty or No Contest

Thank you for your time and consideration!

Comment: Isn't it multiple choice?

Comment: You could call it a ternary choice.

Answer (score 1):

A three-way split is a [trichotomy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trichotomy_(philosophy)).

> A  three-way classificatory division

Answer (score 0):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic)

> In logic, a **three-valued logic** (also **trinary logic, trivalent, ternary**, or **trilean**,[citation needed] sometimes abbreviated **3VL**) is any of several many-valued logic systems in which there are three truth values indicating true, false and some indeterminate third value. This is contrasted with the more commonly known bivalent logics (such as classical sentential or Boolean logic) which provide only for true and false. Conceptual form and basic ideas were initially created by Jan Łukasiewicz and C. I. Lewis. These were then re-formulated by Grigore Moisil in an axiomatic algebraic form, and also extended to n-valued logics in 1945.